# Filter extended IdentityUserRole when granting credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to create an authentication server for multiple applications with Owin.

For that purpose i'm adding a clientId to my AspNetUserRole table like this.

```
public class ApplicationUserRoles : IdentityUserRole
{
    public ApplicationUserRoles() : base() { }

    [Key]
    public  string ClientId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
    public Audience Client { get; set; }

}
```

That is working fine.

What I can't find is where to override the role list creation when i'm doing the `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` so i can filter only de roles for the current cilentId.

I tried to change it in UserManager `FindAsync(username,password)` but Roles is readonly.

I thing maybe I should override something on UserStore but i'm not sure which method should be overrided, and how I can be sure i'm loading all the other data such as claims and logins and checking all the security concerns it already does.

Any idea will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok
I'm sure this isn't the best answer but it works and i'm sure it doesn't change anything in the indentity flow.

I change in my `ApplicationUserManager` the create identity method. I take thw identity created by owin, remove the role claims it already has and add new ones from the rolesi want.

```
public override async Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user, string authenticationType)
    {

          var identityClaims = await base.CreateIdentityAsync(user, authenticationType);
        List<Claim> claimsDelete = new List<Claim>();
        foreach (var claim in identityClaims.Claims)
        {
            if (claim.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)
                claimsDelete.Add(claim);
        }

        foreach(var claim in claimsDelete)
            identityClaims.TryRemoveClaim(claim);

        var roleStore = new RoleStore();
        var roles = roleStore.GetAll();

        for (int i = 0; i < user.Roles.Count(); i++)
            {

                if (((ApplicationUserRoles)((List<IdentityUserRole>)user.Roles)[i]).ClientId == this.clientId)
                {
                   identityClaims.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, roles[((List<IdentityUserRole>)user.Roles)[i].RoleId]));
                }

            }


        return identityClaims;
    }
```